Using webpack to bundle up cdk lambda
I am building a cdk stack including a bunch of lambda functions. My goal here is to update all the node to es6 so I can use tree shaking, and use Webapck to hugely optimise the individual lambda bundles. I'm also updating the AWS-SDK to version 3 so I can take advantage of the leaner imports of individual packages and use bare bones clients etc. Basically anything I can think of to trim any fat off the code so speed it up and save a few $$$.
The folder structure of the relevant parts of the project:
monkey-cloud/
├──lambda
│  ├── src/
│  │   ├── release/
│  │   │   ├── image-get.js
│  │   │   ├── image-put.js
│  │   ├── critical/
│  │   │   ├── data_iot.js
│  │   │   ├── data-get.js
│  │   │   ├── device-put.js
│  │   │   ├── device-get.js
│  ├── includes/
│  │   ├── dynamodb/
│  │   │   ├── monkey_dynamodb.js
│  │   ├── s3/
│  │   │   ├── monkey_s3.js
│  ├── dist/
├── webpack.config.js
├── package.json

What I have done so far is install webpack & a bunch of other stuff:
npm install --save-dev webpack webpack-cli babel-loader @babel/core @babel/preset-env

Then I've created a webpack.config.js at the root of the project:
const path = require('path');
const glob = require('glob');

// Automatically find all Lambda entry points
const entry = glob.sync('./lambda/src/**/*.js').reduce((acc, file) => {
    const name = path.relative('./lambda/src', file).replace(/\.js$/, '');
    acc[name] = file;
    return acc;
}, {});

module.exports = {
    entry,
    output: {
        filename: '[name]/index.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'lambda/dist'),
        libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
    },
    mode: 'production',
    target: 'node',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
                    },
                },
            },
        ],
    },
    optimization: {
        usedExports: true,
    },
};

I've added a simple script into the package.json
"//-full-build": "webpack  && node ./lambda/lambda-zip.js",
"build": "webpack"

And last piece of the puzzle, I've added a little node.js script to do some build stuff (lambda-zip.js) - essentially to clean up the outputs into a format that is ready to use by cdk when I actually deploy the project. N.B. I've temporarily disabled that step above.
To test the progress so far, I can just run npm run build. Ideally, this should bundle up my lambdas into a nice clean tree of zipped files to shove into my cdk lambdas as code.
It's not working so smoothly for me... When I run webpack, I end up with a lot of unexpected outputs. I've simplified the project to have only 1 lambda in it (critical/data-iot.js). When I just run webpack and nothing else, it does create the critical/data-iot.js in the dist folder. However, it builds a whole BUNCH of other folders called 109, xyz etc... It looks like it's trying to build a bunch of lazy loaded assets...
If I run webpack with only one lambda the output is like this:

If I run webpack with 2 lambda functions the output looks like this:

I thought this was interesting, because it kind of implies that the contents of the numbered files is shared maybe???
Here's what the terminal shows during webpack running:
$ npm run build

> monkeycloud@1.0.0 build
> webpack

assets by status 97.8 KiB [compared for emit]
  assets by chunk 75.1 KiB (id hint: vendors)
    asset 787.js 20.5 KiB [compared for emit] [minimized] (id hint: vendors)
    asset 526.js 16.8 KiB [compared for emit] [minimized] (id hint: vendors)
    asset 41.js 16.7 KiB [compared for emit] [minimized] (id hint: vendors)
    asset 563.js 10.6 KiB [compared for emit] [minimized] (id hint: vendors)
    asset 920.js 10.6 KiB [compared for emit] [minimized] (id hint: vendors)
  + 8 assets
assets by status 272 KiB [emitted]
  asset data-iot.js 237 KiB [emitted] [minimized] (name: data-iot) 1 related asset
  asset 329.js 21 KiB [emitted] [minimized] (id hint: vendors)
  asset 897.js 6.18 KiB [emitted] [minimized]
  asset 626.js 4.65 KiB [emitted] [minimized]
  asset 789.js 3.65 KiB [emitted] [minimized]
orphan modules 957 KiB [orphan] 733 modules
runtime modules 2.31 KiB 7 modules
built modules 1.02 MiB [built]
  cacheable modules 1010 KiB
    modules by path ./node_modules/@aws-sdk/ 409 KiB 40 modules
    modules by path ./node_modules/@smithy/ 205 KiB 28 modules
    modules by path ./node_modules/fast-xml-parser/src/ 60.6 KiB 11 modules
    modules by path ./node_modules/mnemonist/ 15.8 KiB 3 modules
    modules by path ./node_modules/obliterator/*.js 5.18 KiB
      ./node_modules/obliterator/iterator.js 1.73 KiB [built] [code generated]
      ./node_modules/obliterator/foreach.js 3.45 KiB [built] [code generated]
    + 4 modules
  + 14 modules
webpack 5.91.0 compiled successfully in 5489 ms

Questions

How do I zip up this carnage into a single zip file for each cdk lambda? Or is there something I'm doing wrong?

When I add in the other hundred lambda functions, this is going to get slightly out of control!? Is there some way of forcing webpack to generate a single file for each lambda? And obviously in a sensible predetermined location. Otherwise it's going to be a nightmare to automate the zipping up process.

The guide I was following states that you need to stick to ES6 style imports. Out of interest, why is this, and what happens if you use requires("xxxx") instead?


